# Ordering data from Database alphabetically?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

In my app I have created a List of items which are displayed on the screen using LayoutInflater. The data I am using is been fetched from the database and inflated into the list.

Is there any way to display the data with field based ordering:

This image will make it simpler to understand:-[image]

Now what I am trying to get is when user clicks on "Test" the list is ordered with alphabetically.
When user clicks on "Completion Status" it orders up according to it and so on with other fields.

So anyone who have worked on similar problem may suggest any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us? I think it'd be easier to suggest a possible solution if we can see how you're currently approaching this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute query as

```
    sqlDB.query(tablename, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

eg:
            Cursor c =  sqlDB.query("tablename", null, null, null, null, null, "your_column")

then inflate to layout

Answer (score 2):

You can specify orderby clause to define column fields are to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement sort in database query